# how do you create an app profile for ufw?

Tags: firewall, iptables, ufw

Ufw has a command that lists out profiles to which you can further explore their profile definitions

```
$ ufw app list
```

And

```
$ ufw app PROFILE {app profile title}
```

I was wondering how you can create a profile for an undefined program, like virtual box and have that profile run the same definitions I have given iptables for my Ubuntu distro.

---

Not only am I trying to use Ubuntus firewall to service my virtual machine. I am also sincerely curious as how to create a profile for an application that doesn't come with one.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

To answer the real question, about how to create your own application file, you only need to know that it is using windows INI file format.

```
[appname]
title=1-liner here
description=a longer line here
ports=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,30/tcp|50/udp|53
```

The ports line can specify multiple ports, with /udp or /tcp, to limit the protocol, otherwise it defaults to both.  You have to split the protocol sections up with |.

So, for a real-life set of examples I made:

```
[puppet]
title=puppet configuration manager
description=Puppet Open Source from http://www.puppetlabs.com/
ports=80,443,8140/tcp

[AMANDA]
title=AMANDA Backup
description=AMANDA the Advanced Maryland Automatic Network Disk Archiver
ports=10080
```

You can list multiple versions of the app in a single file, like this one from apache:

```
===start of apache2.2-common file===
[Apache]
title=Web Server
description=Apache v2 is the next generation of the omnipresent Apache web server.
ports=80/tcp

[Apache Secure]
title=Web Server (HTTPS)
description=Apache v2 is the next generation of the omnipresent Apache web server.
ports=443/tcp

[Apache Full]
title=Web Server (HTTP,HTTPS)
description=Apache v2 is the next generation of the omnipresent Apache web server.
ports=80,443/tcp

===end of file===
```

Once you have defined your application file, put it in `/etc/ufw/applications.d`, then tell ufw to reload the application definitions with

```
ufw app update appname
ufw app info appname
```

Use it with something like:

```
ufw allow from 192.168.1.10 to any app amanda
ufw allow amanda
```

assuming 192.168.1.10 is the IP of your amanda server.

Comment: your syntax for combining udp and tcp is wrong. It should be `xx/tcp|yy/udp`. In other words, the separation between protocols should be a pipe, not a comma like in your example

Comment: My example wasn't trying to combine them, it  is a simple list of this-port-on-udp, some-other-port-on-tcp.

Comment: I just tried using `netstat` to find the application name...is that right?  It worked for me at least.  Is it case sensitive?  I'm not really sure what the relationship is between the "appname" in the application file vs. the title vs. the process name, etc.

Comment: Netstat just lists the process name connected to a particular port.  This doesn't necessarily match the name of the application. For example, the postfix application launches a variety of processes, including the 'master' process that opens port 25.   I name the ufw app config file based on, say, the package name, ie 'Postfix' or 'AMANDA'.  Within the config file there are one or more app definitions that represent ports opened by that package. There can be multiples, see the 'postfix' package as an example.  There the app names vary based on how postfix was configured.

Comment: for multiple tcp ports, is it as the former or the latter? `xx/tcp,xy/tcp,xz/tcp` or `xx/tcp|xy/tcp|xz/tcp`

Comment: I can confirm that the port syntax is incorrect.  Ports are delimited with pipes, not just protocols: `ports=1|2|3|4|5/udp|6/udp|7|8/tcp|9/tcp|10|30/tcp|50/udp|53`

Comment: Examples of the syntax taken directly from "man ufw" and the APPLICATION INTEGRATION section:  [SomeService]
         title=Some title
         description=Some description
         ports=12/udp|34|56,78:90/tcp

       In the above example, 'SomeService' may be used in  app  rules  and  it
       specifies  UDP  port  12,  TCP  and UDP on port 34 and TCP ports 56 and
       78-90 inclusive.  The syntax in my original answer is tested and CORRECT.

Answer (score 17):

It's actually all there in the manpage under the "Application Integration" section.

The basic syntax is:

```
ufw allow <app_name>
```

Or you can use the extended syntax to be more specific:

```
ufw allow from <some_address> to any app <app_name>
```

The manpage specifically says *not* to specify a port number:

> You  should  not  specify the protocol with either syntax, and with the
> extended syntax, use app in place of the port clause.

This probably means it will let `<app_name>` use whatever port it wants to..

Other useful commands:

```
ufw app info <app_name>
```

Which lists the information on `<app_name>`'s profile.

```
ufw app update <app_name>
```

Which updates `<app_name>`'s profile. You can use `all` to update all application profiles.

You can use the:

```
ufw app update --add-new <app_name>
```

command to add a new profile for `<app_name>` and update it, following the rules you set out with `ufw app default <policy>`.

App profiles are stored in `/etc/ufw/applications.d` and sometimes `/etc/services`.

For more information see [`man ufw`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/ufw.8.html#application%20integration).

Comment: Yes, you don't specify a port in the 'ufw allow' syntax because the protocol is supposedly specified, if necessary, in the app definition file itself.

Comment: `/etc/services` seems to be just the list of common network services and their standard ports (as assigned by IANA), so other than being a reference it's not directly usable as an UFW application profile

Comment: The original question was asking how to create a custom application definition, not how to use an existing pre-defined ufw application already present.  /etc/services is a unix-standard file that lists ports and what protocol they provide, not what application provides them, and usually lists a lot of services that aren't even present on the host in question.  It's a standard OS resource, not a configuration file.