# ufw application profile to allow for specific source ports

Tags: firewall, ufw, plex

I have UFW and PlexMediaServer setup on my server. I have a UFW profile for PMS as so:

```
[PlexMediaServer]
title=Plex Media Server
description=This opens up PlexMediaServer for http (32400), upnp, and autodiscovery.
ports=32469/tcp|32413/udp|1900/udp|32400/tcp|32412/udp|32410/udp|32414/udp|32400/udp
```

This is almost working. When I check my UFW logs I see entries like this:

```
Mar 28 19:57:03 nook kernel: [331212.683123] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[redacted] SRC=[IP of another computer] DST=[IP of my server] LEN=282 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=56639 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=60721 LEN=262
Mar 28 19:57:28 nook kernel: [331236.942353] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[redacted] SRC=[IP of another computer] DST=[IP of my server] LEN=282 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=57752 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=60721 LEN=262
Mar 28 19:57:47 nook kernel: [331255.970736] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[redacted] SRC=[IP of another computer] DST=[IP of my server] LEN=282 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=58572 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=60721 LEN=262
Mar 28 19:58:07 nook kernel: [331276.296187] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=[redacted] SRC=[IP of another computer] DST=[IP of my server] LEN=282 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=59969 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=1900 DPT=60721 LEN=262
```

I have concluded this is because of PMS. It looks like PMS is trying to do discovery on other devices on my network and those devices are replying but then UFW is blocking them.

So I want to add something to my PMS profile for UFW that allows these requests. I think I need to add something that says allow where source IP matches 192.168.1.X and source port is 1900.

How can I do this?

Comment: Useful information here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/409013/how-do-you-create-an-app-profile-for-ufw

Comment: Thanks. I saw that but couldn't figure out how to do what I am trying to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the router trying to discover devices in your specific subnet. You need to use "**port** *number*" after the "**from** *IP or subnet of origin*" to allow the specific source port.

In my particular use case I use the following command

```
# ufw allow proto udp from 192.168.0.0/24 port 1900 to any comment UPnP
```

Hope it helps you and the people searching this specific problem.