# Does UFW support named rules or rule sets

Tags: ufw

Can I add a bunch of rules with a specific name so that I can later delete just those rules without disturbing any of the other existing ones?

Comment: It supports *application profiles*, which may be what you are looking for - see [how do you create an app profile for ufw?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409013/how-do-you-create-an-app-profile-for-ufw)

Comment: This is for a set of global rules, not rules for a single application

Comment: AFAIK these are not application-based rules in the sense used by other OSes - they are just collections of port-based rules that are collected together as a nominal "application"

Comment: Well, they're still limited basically to either binary name and/or ports affected.  You can't specify more generic rules.