# how do I add a UFW rule to allow gupnp-av-cp application to control TV which is connected to local network?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, ufw

I use `gupnp-av-cp` application to play, pause, volume up/down, stop in short to control media buttons on TV which is connected to local area network. But When I enable `ufw` firewall then it fails to reach TV.

I added a rule to  `/etc/ufw/applications.d/gupnp-av-cp`

```
 [gupnp-av-cp]
 title=Media Controller
 description=Local Area Media
 ports=80,60999/tcp
```

reloaded `ufw`

```
 sudo ufw reload
```

but it doesn't work properly.

I don't know which port ranges to allow

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm informed, you have just given ufw the information about a protocol. But now you have to enable it.
You can perform this with the following command:

```
ufw app update gupnp-av-cp
ufw allow gupnp-av-cp
```

Then you can reload ufw and it should work.

Also consider looking at: [how do you create an app profile for ufw?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409013/how-do-you-create-an-app-profile-for-ufw)

Comment: I get `ERROR: Could not find a profile matching 'gupgp-av-cp'`

Comment: @kenn I think the poster just mis-read your app name (swap `gupgp-` for `gupnp-`)

Comment: Yes, I mistyped it. It should be `gupnp`, not `gupgp`. (I corrected it in the answer...

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you for your attention.  I feel dumb, I also retyped it many times and supposedly rechecked the spelling. I think I stop to trust in my perception.
Anyway, I allowed `gupnp-av-cp`, when I restart  `gupnp-av-cp` it can not access to local TV. I need to add correct ip port ranges for `tcp` and `udp`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have to apply the following steps:

I added a rule to `/etc/ufw/applications.d/gupnp-av-cp`

```
[gupnp-av-cp]
title=Media Controller
description=Local Area Media
ports=80:60999/tcp|1900:60999/udp
```

Then

```
sudo ufw allow  from 192.168.1.110/24 to any app gupnp-av-cp
```

Finally

```
sudo ufw reload
```

You also need to enable `UPNP` in your modem.
`192.168.1.110` is local ip address of my computer.